# SVG Path Hit-Testing

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, mouseover, jquery-svg

I am having problems detecting mouseover events on SVG path elements.  It seems that the smaller the strokeWidth for the path element, the less success I have in detecting the mouseover.

Also, I am using jquery-svg plugin to do the drawing.

Below is a fiddle of trying to detect using a jquery mouseover event on the path element.
[Mouseover Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwoodsmall/jEatE/2/)

Below is a fiddle of trying to detect by attaching a mousemove listener to svg, then using document.getElementFromPoint.
[getElementFromPoint Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwoodsmall/ZP2TK/76/)

Neither of these seem to work reliably, especially if the mouse is moving fast.  Is it possible to make either of these more sensitivity to better detect the mouseover? Or perhaps a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way browsers work, you don't get `mouseover` events continuously, but you get one each time the operating system updates the cursor position. And if the mouse is moving fast, you will get a events a few pixels apart. The mouse doesn't *slide* over the document, it *jumps*. [Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NAnys/1/) showing where each event occurs. There's nothing that you can do to get `mouseover` events for all the elements between two consecutive positions of the cursor.

You could do something different: remember the previous location of the `mousemove` event, compute the line between that point and the current mouse position, and compute all the intersections between this line and all the other shapes in the document. But that is going to be resource-intensive, since there's no API available for that, you'll have to compute intersections yourself. There is a [library](http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/math/intersection/index.htm) that can help you.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__getIntersectionList is an SVG DOM API for getting all elements that intersect a given rectangle (which in this case would be the mouse movement line).

Comment: Right, but there are two problems: that checks the whole rectangle between the two points, not just the line, but that's not so bad; the other is that [it's not implemented yet in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=501421)

Comment: The latter is the most concerning to me, I just tested my solution using @Eriks suggestion, and it does not work in Firefox

Comment: @SergiuDumitriu I took your suggestion and computed the intersections myself.  Thanks for the advice.  Also, your fiddle displaying where each event occurs was very informative, I didn't realize how mousemove and other events worked.